# Is it possible to tell if pairs of values are sampled from the same distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, sampling

Let's say I construct two lists, $A$ and $B$, each containing $N$ pairs of values.

For $A$, the $i$th pair of values, $(A_{i,1}, A_{i,2})$, consists of two samples from some arbitrary probability distribution. **This distribution is not necessarily the same for each pair.** (This means that $A_{i,1}$ and $A_{j,1}$ are NOT sampled from the same distribution)

For $B$, the $i$th pair of values, $(B_{i,1}, B_{i,2})$, consists of one sample each from two arbitrary probability distributions.

If I gave you two lists constructed in this way, could you tell which is which?

---

Is the fact, that the values $A_{i,1}$ and $A_{i,2}$ come from the same distribution (thus, "correlated" in a way) and that $B_{i,1}$ and $B_{i,2}$ do not, sufficient to distinguish the two lists even for extremely large values of $N$?

What information at minimum is required to distinguish two lists constructed in this way as $N \to \infty$?

Comment: Sounds like for two pairs you will not have enough statistical power to do anything meaningful, i.e., to test at sufficient confidence whether both lists come from the same distribution. For longer lists, this test does what you are asking: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test

Comment: That's the $N = 1$ case, which as you point out, is meaningless to consider. My question is whether we can do better for large $N$.

Comment: Are the two distributions for the pairs in $B$ also not necessarily the same for each pair?

Comment: For $B$ every value is sampled from a completely different arbitrary distribution (both within and outside the pairs).

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough observations, and if the two distributions are sufficiently different, then it
should not be difficult to distinguish between
the A's and B's.

For both A and B take differences of the pairs.
$A_{1i}$ and $A_{2i}$ come from the same distribution, so that the differences $D_{ai}$ should be consistently small.

By contrast $B_{1i}$ and $B_{2i}$ may, at random be
from different distributions, so differences $D_{bi}$ will be a mixture of large and small, and hence have a larger variance.

A variance test on the $D_a$ vs. $D_b$ should detect
the difference in variances.

```
set.seed(2020)
n = 20

mu.a = sample(c(10,50), n, rep=T)
a1 = rnorm(n, mu.a, 2)
a2 = rnorm(n, mu.a, 2)
da = a1-a2

mu.b1 = sample(c(10,50), n, rep=T)
mu.b2 = sample(c(10,50), n, rep=T)
b1 = rnorm(n, mu.b1, 2)
b2 = rnorm(n, mu.b2, 2)
db = b1-b2

var(da); var(db)
[1] 8.959197
[1] 595.5409

var.test(da,db)

    F test to compare two variances

data:  da and db
F = 0.015044, num df = 19, denom df = 19, 
  p-value = 3.547e-13
alternative hypothesis: 
  true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.005954518 0.038007415
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
         0.0150438
```

Your idea of looking at correlations also seems feasible.

```
cor(a1, a2)
[1] 0.9903569
cor(b1, b2)
[1] 0.2256975

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 plot(a1,a2, pch=20)
 plot(b1,b2, pch=20)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

However, I don't understand the questions about sample
size. I don't see how variances become more alike
as sample size increases. I ran my code with $n=2000$
instead of $n=20.$ The P-value of `var.test` changed
from nearly $0$ to an output of just $0,$ which
probably means a P-value small enough to cause underflow.

And your idea of correlation also works fine with larger
samples:

```
cor(a1,a2)
[1] 0.9902555
cor(b1,b2)
[1] 0.01700688
```

*Notes:*
(1) My only (and lame) reason for not comparing correlations
with a formal test is I didn't want to have to figure
out how to do it in R.
(2) A Welch t test can't tell the difference between `da` and `db` with either sample size.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Consider any two probability density functions $f_1,f_2$. Draw all values for $A$ with density $\frac12(f_1+f_2)$. For each $i$ and $j$, independently uniformly randomly choose $r_{i,j}\in\{1,2\}$, and sample $B_{i,j}$ from $f_{r_{i,j}}$. Then the test has no chance to distinguish the lists (even if $f_1$ and $f_2$ were known), since if you don’t know the $r_{i,j}$ the pairs have identical joint distributions.